# Transform array into fast object lookup

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var seen = {};
$.each([6,7,11], function(i,v){ seen[v] = 1; });

// console.log(seen);
```

Is there more efficient version of above example? Perhaps using `$.map` or `$.extend`?

Comment: Probably a good old loop will be more efficient than calling a function which analyzes the parameter then runs a loop which calls a function.

Comment: You can read the jQuery docs too - try something and let us know how it went, then we can help more. `map` only seems to return an array

Comment: @Ian I've already have, but didn't found anything helpful

Comment: @mpapec So show what you've tried. And if you haven't tried anything, try something. You should have an understanding of the library and its methods, instead of blindly asking a question for us to figure it out for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = arr.length
while (i--) {
  seen[arr[i]]=1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling a function which analyzes the parameters then executes a loop which calls a function, simply do a loop :

```
for (var i=arr.length; i-->0;) seen[arr[i]]=1;
```

jsperf confirms it's much more efficient : http://jsperf.com/each-or-for666

Comment: I think vanilla JavaScript is always faster :) Although it's nice to be able to use `each` on a jQuery object

Comment: `$.each` is often very convenient, especially when you have to be compatible with IE8, but efficiency is not among its strengths.

Comment: I'm not against jQuery at all, but it's really annoying when people start to use jQuery in unnecessary situations just because they can...

Comment: @dystroy Very well put :) What do you mean by "compatible with IE8" though? What doesn't work in IE8?

Comment: He's talking about using the 'forEach' method defined in Javascript 1.6 that IE8 probably doesn't support.

Comment: @Ian I mean when you don't have to be compatible with IE8 you can use `forEach` which isn't especially fast but is convenient.

Comment: @Reimius I have two things for you (which you may have already seen): http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Hk1mt-RKYLc/UOkxShm6NrI/AAAAAAAACqo/LVmqHOfWV7g/s1600/20091116-so-large.gif and http://blog.millermedeiros.com/stop-writing-plugins-start-writing-components/ . My point is that I agree with you :)

Comment: @dystroy Ahh I see. I thought you were referring to the two things we were talking about - `for` loops and `$.each`, so I didn't think you were talking about that. Great point though :)